# Nested conditions throwing syntax error in Power Query (Power BI)

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to create a conditional column based on comparison between existing columns in a power bi table. However there are some syntax error which I am not sure why they are occurring. If someone could guide me, would be great. Thanks. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqD02.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have multiple else statements following each other. This is not allowed, neither syntactically nor logically. The solution is to put the inner if-then-else clauses in brackets and to omit the final outer else clause since it's not necessary at all:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "value 2", each 
    if [low] <> null then 
        ( if (([value] <  2 * [high]) and ([value] > [low]/2)) then [value] else null )
    else 
        ( if ([value] < 2 * [high]) then [value] else null )    
)
```

Comment: Dis this answer work for you?